# Backbone Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I've Started learning Backbone JS, iam getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

**Here is my code:**

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'api/users',
        defaults:{
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            age: 0
        }
    });

    var UsersList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: User,
        url: 'api/users'
    });
    var usersList = new UsersList();


    var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'tr',
        template: _.template($('#user-template').html()),
        render: function(){
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        template: _.template($('#user-list-template').html()),
        initialize: function(){
            this.listenTo(usersList,'reset',this.addAll);
        },
        render: function(options){
            if(options.id){
                var user = new User({id: options.id});
                user.destroy();
                router.navigate('',{trigger:true});
            }

            usersList.fetch({reset: true});
            this.$el.html(this.template());
        },
        addAll: function(){
            usersList.forEach(this.addOne,this);
        },
        addOne: function(user){
            var userView = new UserView({model: user})
            $('.users-list').append(userView.render().el)
        }
    });
    var userListView = new UserListView();


var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            ''    : 'home',
            'new' : 'add-user',
            'edit/:id' : 'edit-user',
            'delete/:id' : 'delete-user',
        }
    });
    var router = new Router();
    router.on('route:home',function(){
        userListView.render();
    });
    router.on('route:add-user',function(){
        addUserView.render();
    });
    router.on('route:edit-user',function(id){
        editUserView.render({id:id});
    });
    router.on('route:delete-user',function(id){
        userListView.render({id:id});
    });
    Backbone.history.start();
```

Its showing me error at this line: `if(options.id){` Iam not understanding why getting that error. Actually I am trying to delete a user from a list.

**Updated:** ( I have below view too, but showing no error for `if(options.id)` ), then why showing error as `id` undefined for `UserListView`? ITs really surprising me. Working for one view, but showing error for another view.

```
var EditUserView =  Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        template: _.template($('#edit-user-template').html()),
        render: function(options){
            if(options.id){
                var user = new User({id: options.id})
                var that = this;
                user.fetch({
                success: function(user){
                    that.$el.html(that.template({user: user}));
                }
            });
            }
        },
        events: {
            'submit .update-user-form' : 'updateUserForm'
        },
        updateUserForm: function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var userDetails = {firstName: $('#firstname').val(), lastName: $('#lastname').val(), age: $('#age').val()};
            var user = new User({id: $('#id').val()});
            user.save(userDetails,{
                success: function(){
                    router.navigate('',{trigger: true});
                }
            });
        }
    });
    var editUserView = new EditUserView();
```

Comment: @Alexander :  Actually I thought to make tick mark after i get reply for my last query..  ie., regarding 'parameter' in the function. I got this doubt after i undestood your answer only. So your answer is helpful for me. you shudn't have removed like that.

Comment: how? but u deleted ur answer

Comment: BTW, u got my last query?